# Positronium bumps in photon-photon scattering

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering-cross-section

Photon-photon scattering cross-sections increase up to an energy of about the rest-mass of a positron-electron pair and then begins to [drop](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Total-photon-photon-scattering-cross-section-barn-vs-energy-MeV-The-thick-black_fig2_232697284). If the center-of-mass energy is higher than the about 1022 keV, it's possible to produce an electron-positron pair.

But suppose you could map this spectrum out with very high frequency resolution.

If the energy was 6.8 eV below the pair-production threshold, it could produce [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) in the 1S state. If it is 1.7 eV below, you could get the 2S or 2P state, and so-on.

Would an extremly close examination of the cross-section show resonance peaks at these ("1022" keV-6.8/n^2 eV) energy locations? Resonance peaks correspond to creating a particle, and positronium is a (composite) particle.