Free Neutron Decay
I've read that free neutrons can decay into hydrogen, but it's rare because the energy from the decay usually sends the electrons away, unable to bind with the protons. But if trillions of free neutrons formed and then decayed around the same time in reasonably close proximity, could most of the decay result in hydrogen formation?

Neutrons decay into a proton, an electron and an anti-electron neutrino. The decay energy is around 780keV if I am not mistaken and that means that the proton and the electron will not form a neutral hydrogen atom unless they can thermalize in the surrounding matter.

@FlatterMann you are wrong. I was also thinking like you did, and was so very shocked to find out the truth.

@naturallyInconsistent How do I get rid of the excess energy in the final products? From kinematics we mostly end up with a proton and an electron that are flying apart rapidly, unless most of the energy is in the anti-electron neutrino? Is that what happens? Maybe my intuition is wrong, then.

@FlatterMann yes to the last possibility. The antineutrino is simply capable of carrying away enough energy for the electron to be bound to the proton.

@naturallyInconsistent Most of the time the neutrino gets all but 13eV of 780keV?

@FlatterMann https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/784220/364064

@naturallyInconsistent So I was right then... the decay into hydrogen is rare. Most of the time we end up with a free proton and a free electron. Thanks for doing the calculation.

@FlatterMann under no circumstance is "that means that the proton and the electron will not form a neutral hydrogen atom unless they can thermalize in the surrounding matter." some form of "So I was right then"; the OP openly stated that it is rare, not your observation.

Related: What would happen to a room full of neutrons?

@naturallyInconsistent You are correct about that. I should have phrased it more carefully. I will try to do better next time.

Definitely, almost obviously.
Most free neutron decay would send the electron out, with only a rare subset having bound hydrogen.
However, at large enough numbers, then an electron that had already been flung out, could lose energy by Bremsstrahlung near a second proton, and then be slowed down enough to be captured by a third proton.

Where does that magic second, third etc. proton come from?

The OP said that there is a lot of neutrons; they all decay, and will make the protons

Trillions of neutrons is not a lot of hydrogen in the final state. Avogadro's number (6e23/mol) is very, very large compared to trillions and high energy electrons require quite a bit of matter to be thermalized.

@FlatterMann that kind of nitpicking is not of any use. The OP had not stated how many trillions; the word is thus more generally applicable as large multiples of Avogadro's number would do.

I wasn't nitpicking. The OP stated trillions. Not to mention that the thermal energy of the recoiling hydrogen atoms will heat the gas to a plasma state anyway, even based on your calculation. So even if we assume opacity, we still end up with a plasma rather than atomic hydrogen.

So let us assume 1 trillion, in a $10000\times 10000 \times10000$ grid spread over a cube with side $a$, then we only have to choose $a$ to give "reasonably close proximity". And then we can try to unambiguously answer the question: whether more than half of them ("most of the decay") end up as hydrogen. Definitely not trivial! (So I upvoted the question...)

@FlatterMann Avogadro number of trillions is still triliions. Avogadro number itself is some trillions. Most hydrogen in the universe are in the plasma state, weakly ionised, so what? Mostly comprised of atomic hydrogen anyway.

@naturallyInconsistent It seems inconsistent that you claim most hydrogen in the universe is "in the plasma state" but then also "mostly comprised of atomic hydrogen". Of course hydrogen plasma is hydrogen, but it is not atomic hydrogen. (Admittedly, for OP's question both would count, since it only asks for "hydrogen". So if OP really meant it like that, then the answer is trivially "yes".)

@JosBergervoet you should look up the definition of plasma. Weakly ionised plasma, in particular. It can even be mostly molecular Hydrogen in its ground state. Considering them as mostly comprised of atomic hydrogen is perfectly fine.

And apart from the definition, even a single proton and electron lightyears apart can be a Rydberg atom. Nobody said it should be in the ground state... (So to answer OP correctly we really need to establish what is meant with "hydrogen" in the question.)

Thank you all for your comments, what I meant by trillions was simply a very large number, not really thinking that a trillion might be low when compared even with Avogadro's number. What I meant by "hydrogen formation" was atomic hydrogen, not ionized or hydrogen plasma. By close proximity I wasn't thinking about confined spaces, just a huge number of free neutrons in any area of the universe all decaying around the same time, if a chain reaction styled production of mostly neutral hydrogen atoms could occur because there would be enough free protons around to capture most of the electrons.

Sorry for lack of clarity and thank you for what you've taught me with your comments.

Lol, @naturallyinconsistent I'll do it, but why the downvotes, is it really a plausible outcome?

It is not very plausible, to be fair.

Let's just crank it out with:
$$ n \rightarrow H + \bar{\nu_e} $$
I'm going to set $m_{\nu}=0$, for ...reasons.
We have:
$$ p^{\mu}_n = (m_n, 0) $$
going to:
$$ p^{\mu}_H = (E', p') $$
$$ p^{\mu}_{\bar\nu_e} = (p', -p') $$
which is trivial in the space part, the time component says:
$$ E' + p' = m_n $$
or
$$ p'^2 + M_H^2 = (m_n-p')^2 = m_n^2 + p'^2 - 2m_np'$$
or:
$$ p' = \frac{m_n^2 - M_H^2}{2m_n} = 0.78145\,{\rm MeV}$$
while
$$ \Delta E = m_n-M_H = 0.78178\,{\rm MeV} = 1.00042 p'$$
which I think means there is not a lot of phase space for that neutrino.

This has nothing to do with the question. The OP explicitly stated that it is rare for the free neutron to decay into bound hydrogen. That part is not going to change just by having a gas of free neutrons. It stands to reason that other mechanisms are intended.
